# convert any date into dateTimestamp in order to compare it

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, admin-panel, date, dateformat

I’m trying to compare the current date timestamp with product special price end date. 
to get current date I use :

```
$currentDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
```

and for specialToDate :

```
$promoEndDate = strtotime($product->getSpecialToDate() );
```

the problem is that magento changes the date format when someone changes the admin locale and then strtotime for promo price returns null.
does anyone have an idea how can I retrieve getSpecialToDate() and convert it to timestamp ?

Thank you :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to this way

```
$date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date($product->getSpecialToDate(),
        Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
        null, false
        );
$promoEndDate = strtotime($date);
```

For Date Format :

```
const DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss';
const DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
const DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT       = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
const DATE_PHP_FORMAT           = 'Y-m-d';
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply, I tried your solution, the first part works fine.  but second part sometime doesn't convert date correctly for example :
if we have this date format 11/02/2020:  echo date('d m Y', 1604275200).date("F", 1604275200);
it echos :  11 02 2020February

and for this format: /11/2020 echo  date('d m Y', 1581379200).date("F", 1581379200); 
 02 11 2020November

Comment: please check updated answer. still face issue try to use php date function for change date format

Comment: Thank you so much it Works :)))